# Dynamically changing jTable with HashMap

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, jtable

I didn't write any code yet, so sorry about that but need some direction and clarification before proceeding. Can I create a dynamic link between with a JTable and Hashmap? So when ever my listenrs add something new or delete something, it will update the Hashmap and that would update the JTable, I was thinking of re-creating the JTable everytime a change happens? That is one of my buttons being pressed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `JTable` is just the visible component, the data is contained in a `TableModel`. Any changes inside the model will be reflected in the `JTable` itself. So you can create a `TableModel` that uses a `HashMap` internally.

Here's Oracle's table tutorial for more info

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: *it will update the Hashmap* - the key to using a TableModel it that you DON'T update the HashMap directly. Instead you use methods of the TableModel to update the data in the HashMap and then the model invokes the appropriate fireXXX(...) event to tell the table to repaint itself. In general using a HashMap is not a good structure to hold data in a model, since the order of the data can't be controlled and you can't access an item by its index which is how all the method of the TableModel work.